# MySQL Count not working even doe the query is returning results

Tags: mysql

I am retrieving the count for this select statement.

```
SELECT
    count(video_id),
    3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.482600) ) * cos( radians( videos.lat ) ) * cos( radians(videos.lon) - radians(-0.063200)) + sin(radians(51.482600)) * sin( radians(videos.lat))) AS distance
FROM
    videos
WHERE
    rooms >= 1 AND price <= 3500
HAVING
    distance <= 3
```

It keeps showing empty result for row count but when I remove the `count(video_id)` and use the * it returns the results:

```
SELECT
    *,
    3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.482600) ) * cos( radians( videos.lat ) ) * cos( radians(videos.lon) - radians(-0.063200)) + sin(radians(51.482600)) * sin( radians(videos.lat))) AS distance
FROM
    videos
WHERE
    rooms >= 1 AND price <= 3500
HAVING
    distance <= 3
```

If there's confusion with the statement it compares the lat and lng of a given location to lat & lng of columns in the table "videos" if the distance is less or equal to 3 miles and returns results.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use **HAVING CLAUSE** if there is no **GROUP BY CLAUSE** one. I can help, but you need to edit your question and add the table structure and describe your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a sub-query like this to count the number of rows:

```
"SELECT count(*) 
 from 
  (SELECT 3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.482600) ) * cos( radians( videos.lat ) ) * cos( radians(videos.lon) - radians(-0.063200)) + sin(radians(51.482600)) * sin( radians(videos.lat))) AS distance 
   FROM videos 
   WHERE rooms >= 1 AND 
         price <= 3500 
   HAVING distance <= 3") as Result;
```

Note you must give the subquery an alias ( I called it Result).

I tested a query like this and it worked - so hopefully this will solve problem

Comment: This is is the same as I have done already it is returning "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0005 seconds.)"

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 14 (15 total, Query took 0.0003 seconds.)

Comment: OK you need to include a `group by` clause.

Comment: I updated the SQL to show you.. hope syntax is right.

Comment: I corrected myself again and updated response - hope this work.

Comment: OK Great. its good practice to accept the answer by clicking in the tick underneath the up/down vote arrows at top left of the reply.....this closes off the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT video_id, count(video_id) as num, distance FROM (SELECT video_id ,3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.482600) ) * cos( radians( videos.lat ) ) * cos( radians(videos.lon) - radians(-0.063200)) + sin(radians(51.482600)) * sin( radians(videos.lat))) AS distance FROM videos WHERE rooms >= 1 AND price <= 3500 HAVING distance <= 3) WHERE group by video_id;
```

Or

```
SELECT video_id,count(video_id),3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.482600) ) * cos( radians( videos.lat ) ) * cos( radians(videos.lon) - radians(-0.063200)) + sin(radians(51.482600)) * sin( radians(videos.lat))) AS distance FROM videos WHERE rooms >= 1 AND price <= 3500 GROUP BY video_id HAVING distance <= 3
```

Comment: Doesn't work the second one returns count for independant row so all the row counts are 1 I need total row count. Thanks

Comment: subquery does not work? using `select video_id, count(1)...`